# How to selectively build Qt for VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, build

I have been building Qt library for VS2010 for 4 hours now, and it seems that it will go on for a while. (At the moment it is building something related to javascript.)

Is there an option to just build the stuff I want?

It would be much much easier if I had installed VS 2008 and the prebuilt library of QT for VS 2008. Is this a better option?

Comment: Unless you need to build with specific options (like using the OpenGL backend, which doesn't really work anyway), then prebuilt VS2008 version will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2010 -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-multimedia -no-qt3support -fast
```

Is my fast build setting for Qt - takes about 20mins on a decent single CPU desktop. Webkit is particularly slow to build, it uses lots of complex templated code.

Comment: -no-webkit is indeed the one important switch to speed things up (if you don't need webkit that is). Everything else is almost marginal in comparison. Two more: -nomake demos -nomake examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try `configure.exe --help` to see what can be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to turning items off in `configure` (as other answers have pointed out), you can also `cd src` after running `configure` and only run `nmake` on the `src` directory and not build all the examples, etc. That cuts off quite a bit.